# Why aren't elements evaluated correctly?

Tags: python, numpy, signal-processing

Can someone explain why are all elements of y equals to zero, after I call function?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
def hilbertImpulseResponse(k):
     if k == 0: 
        return 0
     else: 
        return ((2/(np.pi*k)) * (np.sin((np.pi*k)/2)) * (np.sin((np.pi*k)/2)))
size = 5
n = np.arange(-size, size + 1)
y = np.arange(-size, size + 1)

for i in np.arange(-size, size + 1):
    y[i] = hilbertImpulseResponse(i)

print(y)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

`np.arange` is inferring the `dtype` to be `np.int64`. So all values are floored!

Try specifying the `dtype`:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
def hilbertImpulseResponse(k):
     if k == 0: 
        return 0
     else: 
        return ((2/(np.pi*k)) * (np.sin((np.pi*k)/2)) * (np.sin((np.pi*k)/2)))
size = 5
n = np.arange(-size, size + 1, dtype=np.float64)
y = np.arange(-size, size + 1, dtype=np.float64)

for i in np.arange(-size, size + 1):
    y[i] = hilbertImpulseResponse(i)

print(y)
```

Answer (score 0):

How do you want to use `y` in the rest of the process? It might be better to store these values in a standard Python `dict`:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
def hilbertImpulseResponse(k):
     if k == 0: 
        return 0
     else: 
        return ((2/(np.pi*k)) * (np.sin((np.pi*k)/2)) * (np.sin((np.pi*k)/2)))
size = 5

y = {i:hilbertImpulseResponse(i) for i in range(-size, size + 1)}

print(y)
```

or perhaps as duples:

```
y = [(i,hilbertImpulseResponse(i)) for i in range(-size, size + 1)]
```

or even just generate the `hilbertImpulseResponse` values when needed.

Comment: This doesn't directly answer the question.